# implement move constructor & move assignment operator in c++98 for better performance

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, copy-constructor, c++98

Can I simulate move constructor & move assignment operator functionality with copy constructor and assignment operator in C++98 to improve the performance whenever i know copy constructor &  copy assignment will be called only for temporary object in the code OR i am inserting needle in my eyes?

I have taken two example's one is normal copy constructor &  copy assignment operator and other one simulating move constructor & move assignment operator and pushing 10000 elements in the vector to call copy constructor.

**Example(copy.cpp) of normal copy constructor &  copy assignment operator**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class MemoryBlock
{
public:

   // Simple constructor that initializes the resource.
   explicit MemoryBlock(int length)
      : _length(length)
      , _data(new int[length])
   {
   }

   // Destructor.
   ~MemoryBlock()
   {

      if (_data != NULL)
      {
         // Delete the resource.
         delete[] _data;
      }
   }


//copy constructor.
MemoryBlock(const MemoryBlock& other): _length(other._length)
      , _data(new int[other._length])
{

      std::copy(other._data, other._data + _length, _data);
}

// copy assignment operator.
MemoryBlock& operator=(MemoryBlock& other)
{
  //implementation of copy assignment
}

private:
   int  _length; // The length of the resource.
   int*  _data; // The resource.
};


int main()
{
   // Create a vector object and add a few elements to it.
   vector<MemoryBlock> v;
   for(int i=0; i<10000;i++)
   v.push_back(MemoryBlock(i));

   // Insert a new element into the second position of the vector.
}
```

**Example(move.cpp) of simulated move constructor &  move assignment operator functionality with copy constructor &  copy assignment operator**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class MemoryBlock
{
public:

   // Simple constructor that initializes the resource.
   explicit MemoryBlock(int length=0)
      : _length(length)
      , _data(new int[length])
   {
   }

   // Destructor.
   ~MemoryBlock()
   {

      if (_data != NULL)
      {
         // Delete the resource.
         delete[] _data;
      }
   }


// Move constructor.
MemoryBlock(const MemoryBlock& other)
{
   // Copy the data pointer and its length from the 
   // source object.
   _data = other._data;
   _length = other._length;
   // Release the data pointer from the source object so that
   // the destructor does not free the memory multiple times.
   (const_cast<MemoryBlock&>(other))._data  = NULL;
    //other._data=NULL;
}

// Move assignment operator.
MemoryBlock& operator=(const MemoryBlock& other)
{
   //Implementation of move constructor
   return *this;
}

private:
   int  _length; // The length of the resource.
   int*  _data; // The resource.
};


int main()
{
   // Create a vector object and add a few elements to it.
   vector<MemoryBlock> v;
   for(int i=0; i<10000;i++)
   v.push_back(MemoryBlock(i));

   // Insert a new element into the second position of the vector.
}
```

I observed performance is improved with some cost:

```
$ g++ copy.cpp -o copy
$ time ./copy 
real    0m0.155s
user    0m0.069s
sys 0m0.085s

$ g++ move.cpp -o move
$ time ./move 
real    0m0.023s
user    0m0.013s
sys 0m0.009s
```

We can observe that performance is increased with some cost.

- Has any pitfall to implement move constructor and move assignment
  operator simulated functionality in c++98, even I am sure that copy
  constructor & assignment only call when temporary objects are
  created?
- Has there any other way/technique to implement the move constructor
  and assignment operator in c++98?

Comment: [OT]: delete null pointer is noop, so the check is unneeded.

Comment: [Dietmar Kühl talks about move semantics, including how to mimic the behaviour in C++98.](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/2135)

Comment: @ Jarod42, yes, length assignment  i missed it.

Comment: Your const-cast is Undefined Behaviour.  Your "Move Constructor" has no idea if it has been handed an actually const instance of a Memory Block.  `std::auto_ptr` has something similar to move semantics, and that involves dealing with a constructor taking a non-const reference to the object.

Comment: @AndreKostur The assignment _may_ have undefined behaviour. (It's definitely poor style and unsafe code.) The cast itself does not.

Comment: Move semantics cannot be implemented in C++98. A simulation will probably be buggy by design. And will most likely not be able to replicate the real thing. The best solution is to upgrade to a newer C++. If this is not possible, you can try looking for other ways of optimization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will not be able to have the language understand R-values in the same way that C++11 and above will, but you can still approximate the behavior of `move` semantics by creating a custom "R-Value" type to simulate ownership transferring.

## The Approach

"Move semantics" is really just destructively editing/stealing the contents from a reference to an object, in a form that is idiomatic. This is contrary to copying from immutable views to an object. The idiomatic approach introduced at the language level in C++11 and above is presented to us as an overload set, using l-values for copies (`const T&`), and (mutable) r-values for moves (`T&&`).

Although the language provides deeper hooks in the way that lifetimes are handled with r-value references, we can absolutely *simulate* the move-semantics in C++98 by creating an `rvalue`-like type, but it will have a few limitations. All we need is a way to create an overload set that can disambiguate the concept of copying, from the concept of moving.

Overload sets are nothing new to C++, and this is something that can be accomplished by a thin wrapper type that allows disambiguating overloads using tag-based dispatch.

For example:

```cpp
// A type that pretends to be an r-value reference
template <typename T>
class rvalue { 
public:
    explicit rvalue(T& ref) 
        : _ref(&ref)
    {

    }

    T& get() const {
        return *_ref;
    }

    operator T&() const {
        return *_ref;
    }

private:
    T* _ref; 
};

// returns something that pretends to be an R-value reference
template <typename T>
rvalue<T> move(T& v)
{
    return rvalue<T>(v);
}
```

We won't be able behave *exactly* like a reference by accessing members by the `.` operator, since that functionality does not exist in C++ -- hence having `get()` to get the reference. But we can signal a means that becomes idiomatic in the codebase to destructively alter types.

The `rvalue` type can be more creative based on whatever your needs are as well -- I just kept it simple for brevity. It might be worthwhile to add `operator->` to at least have a way to directly access members.

I have left out `T&&` -> `const T&&` conversion, `T&&` to `U&&` conversion (where `U` is a base of `T`), and `T&&` reference collapsing to `T&`. These things can be introduced by modifying `rvalue` with implicit conversion operators/constructors (but might require some light-SFINAE). However, I have found this rarely necessary outside of generic programming. For pure/basic "move-semantics", this is effectively sufficient.

## Integrating it all together

Integrating this "rvalue" type is as simple as adding an overload for `rvalue<T>` where `T` is the type being "moved from". With your example above, it just requires adding a constructor / move assignment operator:

```cpp
    // Move constructor.
    MemoryBlock(rvalue<MemoryBlock> other)
        : _length(other.get()._length),
          _data(other.get()._data)
    {
        other.get()._data = NULL;
    }

    MoveBlock& operator=(rvalue<MemoryBlock> other)
    {
        // same idea
    }
```

This allows you to keep copy constructors idiomatic, and simulate "move" constructors.

The use can now become:

```cpp
MemoryBlock mb(42);

MemoryBlock other = move(mb); // 'move' constructor -- no copy is performed
```

Here's a [working example on compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/hKNwVe) that compares the copy vs move assemblies.

## Limitations

### No PR-values to `rvalue` conversion

The one notable limitation of this approach, is that you *cannot* do PR-value to R-value conversions that would occur in C++11 or above, like:

```cpp
MemoryBlock makeMemoryBlock(); // Produces a 'PR-value'

...

// Would be a move in C++11 (if not elided), but would be a copy here
MemoryBlock other = makeMemoryBlock();
```

As far as I am aware, this cannot be replicated without language support.

### No auto-generated move-constructors/assignment

Unlike C++11, there will be no auto-generated move constructors or assignment operators -- so this becomes a manual effort for types that you want to add "move" support to.

This is worth pointing out, since copy constructors and assignment operators come for free in some cases, whereas move becomes a manual effort.

### An `rvalue` is not an L-value reference

In C++11, a named R-value reference *is* an l-value reference. This is why you see code like:

```cpp
void accept(T&& x)
{
    pass_to_something_else(std::move(x));
}
```

This named r-value to l-value conversion cannot be modeled without compiler support. This means that an `rvalue` reference will *always* behave like an R-value reference. E.g.:

```cpp
void accept(rvalue<T> x)
{
    pass_to_something_else(x); // still behaves like a 'move'
}
```

## Conclusion

So in short, you won't be able to have full language support for things like PR-values. But you can, at least, implement a means of allowing efficient moving of the contents from one type to another with a "best-effort" attempt. If this gets adopted unanimously in a codebase, it can become just as idiomatic as proper move-semantics in C++11 and above.

In my opinion, this "best-effort" *is worth it* despite the limitations listed above, since you can still transfer ownership more efficiently in an idiomatic manner.

---

**Note:** I do *not* recommend overloading both `T&` and `const T&` to attempt "move-semantics". The big issue here is that it can unintentionally become destructive with simple code, like:

```cpp
SomeType x; // not-const!
SomeType y = x; // x was moved?
```

This can cause buggy behavior in code, and is not easily visible. Using a wrapper approach at least makes this destruction much more explicit

Comment: Example for your bootnote would be `auto_ptr`

Comment: I'm not sure who down-voted this solution, but care to provide an explanation so that I may address feedback?